# What does 'swear' mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> Ron glanced at Hermione, then said, "What if pure-bloods and half-bloods **swear** a Muggle-born's part of their family? I'll tell everyone Hermione's my cousin -"
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows</sub>

I've look it up in [this dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/swear). But I don't know which definition fits. What does 'swear' mean here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the story, but I expect that it is this meaning:

1. To make a solemn declaration ... to the honesty or truth of ... a declaration.

Many verbs can be followed by a **that-clause**: you can check in the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/swear) to see whether it is permitted for a particular verb.  In such cases, the word **that** should always be written, but it is often omitted in spoken english. The passage is in quotes, so it's supposed to be spoken english, and a **that** has been omitted. It might be easier to understand if you add the [that]:

> What if pure-bloods and half-bloods swear [that] a Muggle-born's part of their family?

Comment: Oh, I see it now. I thought ‘ Muggle-born's’ is a possessive.